# How to open a Kotlin Class uisng Java Class in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am calling one button click listener in my java class that will open the Kotlin class fragment. I have written the code but facing a small issue related to a new instance in java class. Please guied on this.

Java Class Code:

```
notifications.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager fp = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ok = fp.beginTransaction();
                ok.add(R.id.fragment_container_dashboard, Weather.newInstance());
                ok.addToBackStack(null);
                ok.commit();
            }
        });

*Can not resolve the method 'newInstance' in 'Weather.'
```

Kotlin Class:

```
class Weather : Fragment()  {
 override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Get the custom view for this fragment layout
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.weather, container, false)
    }
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Replace `Weather.newInstance()` with `new Weather()`. This isn’t a Kotlin-related thing. You would have to call the constructor if the class were defined in Java as well if you haven’t created a factory method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `newInstance()` is placed in the `companion object` of `Weather` fragment class, from within Java code you can call it like this:
`Weather.Companion.newInstance()`